# HTML CSS Printing - Insert "Continued..." text before a page break (auto)

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

HTML with `@media print`  style is rendered through [PDFreactor](http://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/) tool to generate PDF file.

One of the page in HTML file contains an html table. Number of rows in the table are dynamic and inserted using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) Java and hence can flow through multiple pages. Table is breaking automatically with repeating `<thead>`.

Now, the requirement I need help in is to Insert text **continued....**  when the page breaks automatically.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for this would be to dynamically insert additional table rows just before the end of the page which contain the text "continued...".

PDFreactor has a pretty powerful JavaScript engine, which allows DOM modification during layout and access to internal layout data, so you can use the following script which does exactly that:

```
var CONTINUED_TEXT = "continued...";
var currentPage = 0;

// iterate over tables
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    var table = tables[i];

    // determine number of columns
    var cells = table.firstElementChild.querySelectorAll("tr:first-child td, tr:first-child th");
    var colspan = cells.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var cellColspan = parseInt(cells[i].getAttribute("colspan"));

        if (cellColspan) {
            colspan += cellColspan - 1;
        }
    }

    // iterate over rows
    var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        var row = rows[j];
        var bd = ro.layout.getBoxDescriptions(row);

        if (bd) {

            // check if a page break occurs
            if (bd[0].pageIndex > currentPage) {

                currentPage = bd[0].pageIndex;

                if (j > 0) {

                    var previousRow = rows[j - 1];

                    // create a new row
                    var continueRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    var continueCell = document.createElement("td");
                    continueCell.setAttribute("colspan", colspan);
                    continueCell.textContent = CONTINUED_TEXT;
                    continueRow.className = "continueRow";
                    continueRow.appendChild(continueCell);
                    previousRow.parentNode.insertBefore(continueRow, previousRow);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this basically iterates over all rows of a table and finds out if a page break occurs by querying PDFreactor's layout information. Then it will dynamically insert a new table row with the "continued..." text just before the break by manipulating the DOM.

To add this script to PDFreactor, use the API method

pdfReactor.addUserScript("", "url/to/script.js", false);

It is also possible to add the script directly to your document. In this case, make sure that JavaScript mode is enabled like this:

pdfReactor.setJavaScriptMode(PDFreactor.JAVASCRIPT_MODE_ENABLED);

I don't think this can be done by using CSS only. Hope this helps.